# WSO2 how to change response from string to xml

Tags: xml, string, wso2

My application response is a xml like:

> <?xml
>   version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><message><header>
>   <TransactionID>1</TransactionID>
>   <Timestamp>2012-04-21 14:47:28</Timestamp>
>   <OpCode>BOSS_DELETE_USER_SME.CD</OpCode>
>   <MsgType>RESP</MsgType>
>   <ReturnCode>3001</ReturnCode>
>   <ErrorMessage>???????</ErrorMessage>
>   </header><body/></message>

But in ESB,the response like :

> &lt ;?xml
>   version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?&gt ;&lt ;message&gt ;&lt ;header&gt ; 
>     &lt ;TransactionID&gt ;1&lt ;/TransactionID&gt ;        &lt
>   ;Timestamp&gt ;2012-04-21 14:47:28&lt ;/Timestamp&gt ;        &lt
>   ;OpCode&gt ;BOSS_DELETE_USER_SME.CD&lt ;/OpCode&gt ;      &lt
>   ;MsgType&gt ;RESP&lt ;/MsgType&gt ;       &lt ;ReturnCode&gt ;3001&lt
>   ;/ReturnCode&gt ;     &lt ;ErrorMessage&gt ;???????&lt
>   ;/ErrorMessage&gt ;   &lt ;/header&gt ;&lt ;body/&gt ;&lt ;/message&gt
>   ;

How to set in outSequence? I have tried use contentType and messageType,but no use.

Best regards.

Comment: Were you able to figure out the answer to this question?  I'm running into a similar scenario where I keep getting back application/xml content-type response header, but the payload coming back is really JSON.

Answer (score 0):

What is the content type of the response message?( Looks like it is not text/xml. You may use the tcpmonitor to find that out. ) If the content type is found, then you can set the correct message formatter in axis2.xml. (i.e. application/xml formatter).

Comment: Thanks for your advise.My response contentType is:text/plain. And then I set <messageBuilder contentType="text/plain"                      class="org.wso2.carbon.relay.BinaryRelayBuilder"/>. But the response is a binary like this: <ns:binary xmlns:ns="http://ws.apache.org/commons/ns/payload"..PD94bWwgdmVyc2lvbj0......</ns:binary>. Can you help me? Best regards

Comment: Use following builder and formatter in axis2.xml. org.apache.axis2.format.PlainTextBuilder, org.apache.axis2.format.PlainTextFormatter

Comment: Thanks for your advise. I opened axis2.xml,but I have not seen PlainTextBuilder and PlainTextFormatter in ESB4.0.0 or 4.0.3. Could you tell me how to added it? Thank you very much.